# Cannot open folder path directly from html <a> tag in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I have created django template as:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block title %}Checker{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

        <a href="D:/Plagiarism Checker/plagiarismchecker/assignments/datasets/file161.pdf">Click to open a pdf</a>

   </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Whenever I try open that link **Click to open a pdf**  it doesnot open that link.

I try this same process in plain html template it works as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Code</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Opening a folder from HTML code</h1>
   <a href="D:/Plagiarism Checker/plagiarismchecker/assignments/datasets/file161.pdf">Click to open a 
 folder</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to open that link from django template. But I cannot open that path. I will be very thankful if you can resolve this problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inform Django about the paths where you want it to look-up a file by adding the paths to STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py.

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

Once you have added say up to the `plagiarismchecker` folder in STATICFILES_DIRS, you can call the file from the template like this `<a href="{% static 'assignments/datasets/file161.pdf' %}">`

You paths need to be relative to the paths in STATICFILES_DIRS